# How to configure Cron job in magento 2 to enable extensions through component manager?

Tags: magento2, cron

Hello i have uploaded an extension through cpanel and now want to enable it, so whenever i enable it through component manager and start readiness check i get error msg - Error from Setup Application Cron Script:
Cron job has not been configured yet.
So now i have to add a new cron job so plz give me the command to enable module.I will add cron job through Cpanel. or let me know if there is any other way to enable extensions(have added extension through cpanel and cleared the cached but extensions can't be enabled)
"I am new to magento 2". Thanks!

Comment: You have SSH details ?

Comment: If you have SSH detail then you can enable extension by command line, run this command from your root after login SSH.   php bin/magento setup:upgrade and php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy.

Comment: Hello sir i want to know from where i have to run that comand. Thanks!

Comment: Working my suggested solution for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want enable extension by command line, Login with SSH detail.

Go to project root directory and run below commands.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy